# Excel Sum using simple condition

Tags: excel

I'm trying to do what I'm sure is super easy but I'm stuck for a while now. I'm basically trying to sum the values of a colum when the month associated if lower than the one given.

```
Year    Month     Installment    Interest
0   0       
1   1    1.367,61 €      767,71 € 
1   2    1.367,61 €      766,33 € 
1   3    1.367,61 €      764,96 € 
1   4    1.367,61 €      763,57 € 
1   5    1.367,61 €      762,19 € 
1   6    1.367,61 €      760,80 € 
1   7    1.367,61 €      759,41 € 
1   8    1.367,61 €      758,02 € 
1   9    1.367,61 €      756,62 € 
1   10   1.367,61 €      755,22 € 
1   11   1.367,61 €      753,82 € 
1   12   1.367,61 €      752,41 € 
2   13   1.367,61 €      728,08 € 
2   14   1.367,61 €      726,62 € 
2   15   1.367,61 €      725,15 € 
2   16   1.367,61 €      723,68 € 
2   17   1.367,61 €      722,20 € 
2   18   1.367,61 €      720,72 € 
2   19   1.367,61 €      719,24 € 
2   20   1.367,61 €      717,76 € 
2   21   1.367,61 €      716,27 € 
2   22   1.367,61 €      714,77 € 
2   23   1.367,61 €      713,28 € 
2   24   1.367,61 €      711,78 €
```

Let's say I need the sum of interests of the months prior to 22.

Thank you in advance

I've trying to do it by using sumif but I'm not getting correct values, if any.

Comment: possibly `=SUMIF(B2:B42,"<22",D2:D42)` but say you had the number 22 in cell J1 then `=SUMIF(B2:B42,"<" & J1,D2:D42)`